# Visual Studio 2017 Test runner is discovering my tests but not running them

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest

Using the default Visual Studio Testing Framework, the runner is finding all of my tests but when I try to run the tests I get a bunch of tests all part of the same project that are not successfully running. These same tests run fine in Resharper.

is there something that I am missing? there doesn't appear to be any errors when I run the tests, they just don't run at all. (I even called them directly and still have issues.)

Comment: Figured it out, appears it was a setting in visual studio :P

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, apparently having "ForcedLegacyMode" set to true caused the issue. I assume this was automatically turned on by VS 2017 because some of the projects were created in VS 2013.